# Laravel job queue with PDF attached does not work on server but works locally

Tags: php, laravel, job-queue

I allow users to export a PDF file and save it to their PC and I also allow them to send the PDF through email. Since the PDF can take a while to be generated, if the users decide to send it through email, I created a job that handles the creation of the PDF file & sends by email.

My objective is to prevent the user from having to wait while the file is being generated and while the email is being sent.

**Controller**

```
class ReportsController extends Controller
{    
    public function sendByEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $report = (new ReportService)           
            ->setStartAt($request->start_at)
            ->setEndAt($request->end_at)            
            ->setProducts($request->product)
            ->sendByEmail();

        return response()->json([], 200);
    }
}
```

**ReportService**

```
class ReportService
{
    .....
    
    /**
     * Dispatches the job that sends the report by email
     */
    public function sendByEmail(): void 
    {
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SendReportByEmail($this));
    }

    /**
     * Downloads / exports the file
     */
    public function download(): string|Exception
    {        
        $url = (new ReportProductService)
            ->setReportService($this)
            ->download();

        return $url;
    }
}
```

**Job SendReportByEmail**

```
class SendReportByEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public ReportService $reportService) { }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        // Inside the job generates the PDF file
        $url = $this->reportService->download();

        \Mail::queue((new \App\Mails\Report($this->reportService, $url)));
    }
}
```

On local server everything works great.

On production server I'm getting the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to open path "https://my-website/public/reports/products-report-1693859875.pdf". in /home/my_website/public_html/vendor/symfony/mime/Part/TextPart.php:154
```

The file actually exists / is generated, which means the mail is sent faster than the file is being generated. How can I prevent this from happening?

I tried [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#job-batching) and [create a job also for generating the PDF](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/generate-pdf-using-job-and-then-attach-to-queueable-email) but got nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

The code is perfectly fine, but for some reason in the production server the absolute url as an attachment it doesn't work properly. It must be a relative path.

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 */
public function handle(): void
{
    // HERE: $url must be a relative path (at least in my case...)
    $url = $this->reportService->download();

    \Mail::queue((new \App\Mails\Report($this->reportService, $url)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this error and solved it by creating a function that waits for the file to become available.

```
    public function sendByEmail(): void 
{
    $url = $this->download();
    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SendReportByEmail($this, $url));
}
```

Comment: That's not good. If your PDF takes 15 seconds to generate, you'll have to wait those 15 seconds before the job is queued. I just solved my problem, thanks anyway.